# Display new colorbox div after form submitted

Tags: jquery

I have a form that is displayed inline using colorbox.  After the form is submitted, and on success, I want to display a new form saying "thanks for submitting".  I know I could just change the HTML, but I need to keep the original form (div) so that if someone wants to ask another question they just don't see the HTML that replaced the original form.  I have two div's.  First is just a hidden div with form and the second is div id="cbrequestformconfirm".  Right now, after the form button (id=submitrequest) is clicked it does change the colorbox, but it is empty.  Thanks for any help and here is the code.  Let me know if you need additional info.

```
$('#submitrequest2013').click(function(){

    $.post('/form.asp?t='+d.getTime(), $('#communityform').serialize(), function(data) {
       //success
       $("#cbrequestformconfirm").colorbox({inline:true, open:true, width: "50%", Height: "50%"});
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Instead of describing your HTML, could you post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

EDIT: correction to call:

```
$.colorbox({href:"#cbrequestformconfirm",inline:true, open:true, width: "50%", Height: "50%"});
```

where you have this html:

```
<div display="none">
    <div id="cbrequestformconfirm">
        Success!
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes!  Thank you so much fnostro.  Works perfectly.  Preserves original form and everything.  Much appreciated.